# ASM Infinite Loop

Tags: assembly

So far I've got this

```
org 100h


.data
Input db "Enter size of the triangle between 2 to 9: $" 
Size dw ?               


.code
Main proc
Start:
Mov ah, 09h
Mov dx, offset input 
int 21h

mov ah, 01h
int 21h; 

sub al, '0'

mov ah, 0   

mov size, ax 
mov cx, ax    

mov bx, 1                    

call newline


lines:                 
push cx
mov cx, bx
lines2:                 ; outer loop for number of lines
push cx
sub ax,bx  

stars:                 

mov ah, 02h   
mov dl, '*'
int 21h


loop stars

inc bx

call newline
pop cx



loop lines
loop lines2
exit:
mov ax, 4C00H
int 21h     




main endp   


proc newline
mov ah, 02h        
mov dl, 13
int 21h
mov dl, 10
int 21h

ret 


newline endp

 end main
```

Everything works fine and loops through. For instance if I enter 3 I get

```
*
**
***
```

and the program stops however I'm trying to get another loop right after to start giving me something like this:

```
*
**
***

***
**
*
```

but I keep getting into a infinite loop and I can't solve how to fix this issue. does anyone have some insight on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the posted code the working or non working one? If it's the former, post the non working code or we can't tell what's wrong with it.  If you could also indent and comment it, that would be super sweet.

Comment: if you replace "mov cx,bx" in lines with "mov cx,[size]" and "sub cx,bx" you will display the pyramid the other way round

Comment: I ran your code and works great, no infinite loop, congrats!

Comment: @Tommylee2k I tried what you said and i got a infinite loop after two stars displayed.

Comment: Also I added in lines2 hoping that it would display the triangle the other direction and it resulted in another infinite loop. This is usually where I always get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

your loop is running CX from [size] down to 0. so for a pyramid growing, you need to display  ( [size]+1 - CX ) stars. for the one shrinking, it's simply ( CX )

i've moved the "print out BX stars" into a subroutine, this makes it a lot easier to read

```
Start:
    Mov ah, 09h             ; prompt
    Mov dx, offset input 
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h             ; input size
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'
    mov ah, 0   
    mov size, ax 
    mov cx, ax    
    mov bx, 1                    
    call newline

up:                 
    mov bx, [size]      ; number of stars:
    inc bx              ; [size]+1
    sub bx, cx          ; -CX
    call stars
    loop up

    call newline

down:    
    mov cx,[size]
d2:                  
    mov bx, cx           ; number of stars: CX
    call stars
    loop d2


exit:
    mov ax, 4C00H
    int 21h
```

and the subfunction:

```
; display BX number of '*' followed by newline
; uses CX internally, so it's saved and restored before ret
proc stars
    push cx
    mov cx,bx
s2:   
    mov ah, 02h   
    mov dl, '*'
    int 21h
    loop s2

    call newline
    pop cx
    ret
stars endp
```